# Microsoft SQL Server: TSQL Formatting of Results Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a result set of data that has duplicates because certain companies are tied to multiple banks is there a way to combine the values in the BankName column either into a single column.

So the result would be Bendigo Bank, *** Merchant Services on a single row

Or Split them so each row has two bank columns BankName1 with Bendigo Bank As the Value and BankName2 with *** Merchant Services As the value

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `STRING_AGG` to aggregate the bank names. For your query, it might look something like:

```
SELECT … STRING_AGG([BankName], ', ') as [BankNames], …
```

The [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) function will work on all versions of SQL Server since SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Hi Matigo this is aggregating the value multiple times I still have the duplicate rows but the bankname now has bendigo bank - bendigo bank - bendigo bank. 
I will have play with the function and see if I can get it to work. Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use `DISTINCT` in the `STRING_AGG()` function like this: `STRING_AGG(DISTINCT [BankName], ', ')`. It's also possible to `ORDER` the values so that you don't have a situation like `Bank A, Bank B` and `Bank B, Bank A` 